# Replace or Rename String in Between two tags in a line and return as string in java

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to replace or rename a string/tags/keys in-between string in java.

Before jump into my string please notice that there should `Bd` and `Bg` and counts two times. Rename tags for the spouse section. its can remove duplicate and all key/tag is unique

My String is

```
Name : Abul Bashar Fakir , cl : Knit Fabrics Manufacturer , In : 16 June 2003 , Hpc : President , Hpd : Assistant Governor , Bd : April 6 , Bg : B + , Wd : September 27 , Sp : Hossneara Begum , Bd : March 8 , Bg : 0+ , Ma : 98  North Chasara  Narayanganj - 1400 , Tel : ( O ) 01617 008 519  ( R ) 763 2407 , Mob : 01715 393 127  01824 554 123 , Email : basharfokir66@gmail.com
```

Please notice that Here `Bd` and `Bg` count 2 times. one is for the main person and the other is for his/her spouse and Tag is `Sp`. I want to rename all Same tags for Sp with S character append. Example: `Bd` and `Bg` To `SBd`, `SBg` In-between `Sp` tag and `Ma` tag. it will create a unique tag for husband and spouse.

My Targeted String

```
Name : Abul Bashar Fakir , cl : Knit Fabrics Manufacturer , In : 16 June 2003 , Hpc : President , Hpd : Assistant Governor , Bd : April 6 , Bg : B + , Wd : September 27 , Sp : Hossneara Begum , SBd : March 8 , SBg : 0+ , Ma : 98  North Chasara  Narayanganj - 1400 , Tel : ( O ) 01617 008 519  ( R ) 763 2407 , Mob : 01715 393 127  01824 554 123 , Email : basharfokir66@gmail.com
```

> Note: It must return as a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create a unique tag for husband and spouse then
Use Java String replaceFirst() method and rename husband tags with a specific name.

```
 String str = "Name : Abul Bashar Fakir , cl : Knit Fabrics Manufacturer , In : 16 June 2003 , Hpc : President , Hpd : Assistant Governor , Bd : April 6 , Bg : B + , Wd : September 27 , Sp : Hossneara Begum , Bd : March 8 , Bg : 0+ , Ma : 98  North Chasara  Narayanganj - 1400 , Tel : ( O ) 01617 008 519  ( R ) 763 2407 , Mob : 01715 393 127  01824 554 123 , Email : basharfokir66@gmail.com
```

";

```
//Only Replace first 'Bd' with 'HBd' 
String str1 = str.replaceFirst("Bd", "HBd");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace all from the String class. myString.replaceAll("bd", "Sbd")

Comment: sorry sir, i dont want to replace bd and bg for main person but for spouse bd and bg